# excel storing values that are being inputted daily

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have the following input in my excel, which somebody fills in manually every day. The date columns have the following formulas: =WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1) and =WORKDAY(TODAY(),-2)

[image]

At the beginning of every day, someone fills in the correct values of that day.
Now I use the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(AN8,$AB$8:$AC$9,2,FALSE)
```

where AB8:AC9 corresponds to the matrix in figure above. The dates are always the 2 previous days.
Now, I have another column with all the dates from the past months, and for every date I run the above VLOOKUP above and see if the dates match. If the dates match, it shows the correct value. However, if the dates are not a match, it does show #N/A. What I want, is to store the values for previous dates, and not remove it back to #N/A. In other words, every day the value for the previous two days are filled in manually, and I want to store all those historical values in two other columns.

Comment: Could you be more explicit: what is the correct date if none matches the table ?

Comment: Formulas do not just stop working.  You will need vba to copy the data where you want it.  Then it will stay as the dates change.  Or you can copy once a day the paste back just the values in the cells removing the formula.  But if the formula remain it will recalculate and the dates that do not exist in the lookup array will return the error.

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner, do you have an example VBA how this can be done?

Comment: At the risk of asking a really stupid question, why don't you do this the other way round? Get the user to put in the daily figures against the correct date in a big table (you could even use a "Ctrl+T" table with a formula to calculate the date in the first column by incrementing). Then if you want to show the last two days figures somewhere for any reason, use the VLOOKUP (or similar) to fetch them from the "master" table.